# Can the fact that $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y>0\}$ is not an affine variety be generalized?

Tags: affine-varieties

**Background**

I recently encountered this textbook exercise (from *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox) in my abstract algebra course that I found rather interesting:

> Let $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y>0\}$ be the upper half plane. 
>   Prove that $R$ is not an affine variety.

As an assignment, I am to come up with some exercises of my own, and I wanted to see if I can generalize this question at all, which brings us to my question.

---

**Question**

My question might seem strange, and it might not even have an answer, but what I'm wondering is this:  can we extend this result (that the upper half of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not an affine variety) further?

For example, would it be true also that

> $R=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ z>0\}$

is not an affine variety?  Or more generally that

> $R=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x_n>0\}$

isn't an affine variety?

---

**As always, thank you all for taking the time to help me out!**

Comment: Of course it generalizes.  It should be proved the same way.

Comment: An affine subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: And (correct me if I'm wrong) all the examples I listed are not closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?  I haven't learned about affine subvarieties but I think I understand what you're saying.

Comment: In this context, subvariety just means a variety which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: As to the closed property, if a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is zero on a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, then since polynomials are continuous functions, $p$ must be zero on the closure of $S$. It follows that the set of zeros of $p$ is a closed subset of $R^{n}$. But then a variety is just the intersection of the zero sets of a set of polynomials, and an interesection of closed sets is a closed set.

Comment: More generally, if a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ is zero on a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $p$ must be identically zero, hence $p$ is zero on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thus, even a closed half-space would fail to be a variety.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it really made sense!